# Weak maximum principle of strictly elliptic equation with solution in Sobolev space ( Gilberg Trudiger theorem 8.1)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation, regularity-theory-of-pdes

\begin{equation}\label{eq:81}
    Lu=D_i(a^{ij}(x)D_ju+b^i(x)u)+c^i(x)D_iu+d(x)u
\end{equation}

with

\begin{equation}\label{eq:88}
    \int_{\Omega}(dv-b^iD_iv)dx\leq 0\qquad \forall v\geq 0,v\in C_0^1(\Omega)
\end{equation}
Let $u\in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ satisfy $Lu\geq 0(\leq 0)$ in $\Omega$. Then
\begin{equation}\label{eq:89}
    \sup_{\Omega} u\leq \sup_{\partial \Omega}u^+\quad(\inf_{\Omega} u\geq \inf_{\partial \Omega}u^+)
\end{equation}
Proof:
If $u\in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ and $v\in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$ we have $uv\in W_0^{1,1}$ and $D(uv)=vDu+uDv$ .

$\mathfrak L(u,v)\leq 0$
$
\int \{(a^{ij}D_ju+b^iu)D_iv-(c^iD_iu+du)v)\}dx\leq 0$

\begin{equation}
    \int_{\Omega}\{a^{ij}D_juD_iv-(b^i+c^i)vD_iu\}dx\leq \int_{\Omega}\{duv-b^iD_i(uv)\}\leq 0 
\end{equation}
for all $v\geq 0$ such that $uv\geq 0$. last inequality.(Here we used coefficient of u negative).

Hence , by coefficient bounds ,we have
\begin{equation}\label{eq:810}
    \int_{\Omega}a^{ij}D_jD_ivdx\leq 2\lambda\nu\int v|Du|dx
\end{equation}
for all $v\geq 0$ such that $uv\geq 0$.

In special case $b^i+c^i=0$, the proof is immediate by taking $v=\max \{u-l,0\}$ where $l=sup_{\partial \Omega}u^+$.

Suppose on contrary ,$\sup_{\Omega} u> \sup_{\partial \Omega}u^+$
For general case choose $k$ to satisfy $l\leq k<\sup_{\Omega}u,$ and we set $v=(u-k)^+.$( If no such $k$ exists then we are done.\
$v\in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$ and by chain rule
\begin{align*}
Dv = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
                Du & \hspace{5mm} u>k\qquad(v\neq 0) \\
                0 & \hspace{5mm} u\leq k\qquad(v=0)\\
                \end{array} \right.
\end{align*}
Consequently, we obtain above
\begin{equation*}
        \int_{\Omega}a^{ij}D_jD_ivdx\leq 2\lambda\nu\int_{\Gamma} v|Du|dx\qquad \Gamma=supp (Dv)\subset v
\end{equation*}
and Hence by Strict ellipticity of $L$,
\begin{equation*}
    \int_{\Omega} |Du|^2dx\leq 2\nu\int_{\Gamma} v|Du|dx\leq 2\nu ||v||_{2,\Gamma}||Dv||_{2,\Gamma}
\end{equation*}
So that
\begin{equation*}
    ||Dv||_2\leq 2\nu||v||_{2,\Gamma}
\end{equation*}
By theorem 7.10, $n\geq 3$
\begin{equation*}
    ||v||_{2n/(n-2}\leq C||Dv||_2.
\end{equation*}
Also  by Schwartz's inequality
\begin{equation*}
    2\nu||v||_{2,\Gamma}\leq C|\Gamma|^{1/n}||v||_{2n/(n-2)}.
\end{equation*}
So
\begin{equation*}
    ||v||_{2n/(n-2}\leq C|\Gamma|^{1/n}||v||_{2n/(n-2)}.
\end{equation*}
where $C=C(n,v)$ so that
\begin{equation*}
    |\Gamma|\geq C^{-n}>0
\end{equation*}
If $n=2$\
\begin{equation*}
    \sup_{\Omega}|u|\leq C|\Omega|^{1/2-1/p}||Du||_p
\end{equation*}
By replacing $2n/(n-2)$ by any number greater that 2 we get
\begin{equation*}
    |\Gamma|\geq C^{-n}>0
\end{equation*}
As above inequality is independent of $k$, we can take $k\to \sup_{\Omega}u$.
$u $ attain its supremum in $\Omega$ on set of positive measure, where $Du=0$.
This is contradiction to preceding inequality.

I do not understand how to come to contradiction.I understand everything except how contradiction came I don't know.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Strictly speaking, if you have a function, you already have the domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that
$$
\vert \Gamma_k \vert = \int_{\text{supp}(\nabla u)} \mathbb{1}_{\{u \ge k\}}.
$$
Choosing an increasing sequence $\{k_m\}_m$ such that $k_m \to \sup_\Omega u$, we find that $\{\mathbb{1}_{\{u \ge k_m\}}\}_m$ is monotone decreasing.  However, $\vert \Omega \vert < \infty$, so we can apply the decreasing version of the monotone convergence theorem to see that
$$
\lim_{m \to \infty} \int_{\text{supp}(\nabla u)} \mathbb{1}_{\{u \ge k_m\}} = \int_{\text{supp}(\nabla u)} \mathbb{1}_{\{u = \sup_\Omega u\}} =0.
$$
The latter follows from the fact that $\nabla u =0$ a.e. on sets where $u$ is constant.  Combining these shows that $C^{-n} \le \lim_{m \to \infty} \vert \Gamma_{k_m} \vert =0$, and this is the contradiction.

Comment: Thats very nice explanation....